# CKEditor gets destroyed after updating div content via jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

One of my friend's site is using CKEditor 3.6.3. When we update content of a div integrated with CKEditor via jQuery/AJAX, the CKEditor itself get destroyed. How to fix this problem? Note that we can't update CKEditor at this stage.

This is how we integrate CKEditor to our divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<?php
include_once "ckeditor/ckeditor.php";
require_once 'ckfinder/ckfinder.php' ;

$CKEditor = new CKEditor();
$CKEditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$CKEditor->config['width'] = 600;
$CKEditor->textareaAttributes = array("cols" => 80, "rows" => 10);
$initialValue = 'This is some sample text.';
CKFinder::SetupCKEditor( $CKEditor,'ckfinder/') ;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<label for="desc">Description:</label>
<div class="ckeditor" id="desc"><?php $CKEditor->editor('description', $description);?></div>
```

JQuery/AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: startRequest,
    url: "ajax/ajax.php",
    cache: false,
    data: "id="+id,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        if(data.error != "No result found.")
        {
            $("#desc").html(data.desc);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is you're changing the `div`'s `html` where actually there is some iframe and stuff for ckeditor to work correctly. But there's a built-in method to change content of ckeditor. it's `setData`. So you need to do:

```
editor.setData(data.desc);
```